# New features in app cause update to crash

Tags: ios, swift

I've just tried using an updated version of my app on an iPhone which has the version installed that is currently on the app store. I have added a few new features since the last update which seems to cause the app to crash.

Basically, I added a new array that stores data for notes which was not present in previous versions.

This is the code I have in my table view where the app crashes:

```
        cell.notesLabel.text = (notes.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)) as? String
```

The error just states - "Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1"

How can I ensure that users that update from previous versions of the app do not have to delete and reinstall it?

Entire Class:

```
import UIKit

var searchResults = NSArray()

var names: NSMutableArray = []
var dates: NSMutableArray = []
var values: NSMutableArray = []
var images: NSMutableArray = []
var unformatted: NSMutableArray = []
var notes: NSMutableArray = []

class ThirdViewController: UITableViewController, UIAlertViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var addTransactionButton: UIBarButtonItem!
@IBOutlet weak var clearButton: UIBarButtonItem!

let backgroundLabel = UILabel()
var userLeftReview = false
var cellTapped = false
var cellHeight = 0

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    var attributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor(),NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 24)]
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = attributes

    enterButtonTapped = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("viewCheck")
    if enterButtonTapped == false {
        addTransactionButton.enabled = false
    } else {
        addTransactionButton.enabled = true
    }

    if var tempNames: NSArray = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("names") {
        names = tempNames.mutableCopy() as NSMutableArray
    }
    if var tempDates: NSArray = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("dates") {
        dates = tempDates.mutableCopy() as NSMutableArray
    }
    if var tempValues: NSArray = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("values") {
        values = tempValues.mutableCopy() as NSMutableArray
    }
    if var tempImages: NSArray = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("images") {
        images = tempImages.mutableCopy() as NSMutableArray
    }
    if var tempUnformatted: NSArray = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("unformatted") {
        unformatted = tempUnformatted.mutableCopy() as NSMutableArray
    }
    if var tempNotes: NSArray = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("notes") {
        notes = tempNotes.mutableCopy() as NSMutableArray
    }

    self.tableView.reloadData()

    println(notes)
}

func clearAllTransactions() {
    totalBudget = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("totalBudget")!

    names.removeAllObjects()
    values.removeAllObjects()
    dates.removeAllObjects()
    images.removeAllObjects()
    unformatted.removeAllObjects()
    notes.removeAllObjects()

    newTransactionEntered = true
    totalCreditCounter = 0.00
    totalSpendingsCounter = 0.00
    currencyDouble = 0.00
    currentBudgetCalculation = 0.00

    var defaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.AffordIt")
    defaults.setObject(totalBudget, forKey: "currentBudgetWidget")
    defaults.setObject(newTransactionEntered, forKey: "new")

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setDouble(totalCreditCounter, forKey: "creditCounter")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setDouble(totalSpendingsCounter, forKey: "spendingsCounter")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setDouble(currentBudgetCalculation, forKey: "currentCounter")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(currencyDouble, forKey: "doubleCounter")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(names, forKey: "names")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(values, forKey: "values")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(dates, forKey: "dates")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(images, forKey: "images")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(unformatted, forKey: "unformatted")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(notes, forKey: "notes")

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

// #pragma mark - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView?) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController!, shouldReloadTableForSearchString searchString: String!) -> Bool {
    self.filterContentForSearchText(searchString)
    return true
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.

    if tableView == self.searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView {
        return searchResults.count
    } else {
    if names.count == 0 {
        if enterButtonTapped == false {
            backgroundLabel.text = "Before you add any transactions, you must first set a budget. You can do this by tapping the 'Budget' tab."
        } else {
            backgroundLabel.text = "You haven't added any transactions yet. Tap the add button to add a new transaction."
        }
        backgroundLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.width, self.view.bounds.height)
        backgroundLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        backgroundLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        backgroundLabel.sizeToFit()
        backgroundLabel.hidden = false
        backgroundLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 17)
        backgroundLabel.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()

        clearButton.enabled = false

        self.tableView.backgroundView = backgroundLabel
        self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None
        self.tableView.scrollEnabled = false
        return 0
    } else {
        backgroundLabel.hidden = true
        self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.SingleLine
        self.tableView.scrollEnabled = true
        clearButton.enabled = true
        return names.count
    }
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:CustomTransactionTableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CustomTransactionTableViewCell

    var arrowX: CGFloat = 0
    var amountX: CGFloat = 0
    if height == 480 || height == 568 {
        arrowX = 260
        amountX = 152
    } else if height == 667 {
        arrowX = 315
        amountX = 217
    } else {
        arrowX = 354
        amountX = 217
    }

    cell.notesLabel.alpha = 0
    cell.paymentNameLabel.frame.origin.x = 20
    cell.dateLabel.frame.origin.x = 20
    cell.costLabel.frame.origin.x = amountX
    cell.creditArrowImage.frame.origin.x = arrowX
    cell.paymentArrowImage.frame.origin.x = arrowX

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None

    if tableView == self.searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView {
        cell.paymentNameLabel.text = (searchResults.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)) as? String
        var indexValue = names.indexOfObject(searchResults.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row))
        cell.costLabel.text = (values.objectAtIndex(indexValue)) as? String
        cell.dateLabel.text = (dates.objectAtIndex(indexValue)) as? String
        cell.notesLabel.text = (notes.objectAtIndex(indexValue)) as? String

        if images.objectAtIndex(indexValue) as NSObject == 0 {
            cell.paymentArrowImage.hidden = false
            cell.creditArrowImage.hidden = true
        } else if images.objectAtIndex(indexValue) as NSObject == 1 {
            cell.creditArrowImage.hidden = false
            cell.paymentArrowImage.hidden = true
        }

        if notes.objectAtIndex(indexValue) as NSString == "" {
            cell.notesLabel.text = "No notes to display."
        }

        //This works, unless there are two payments with the same name. To revert to previous version, remove tableView if statement and just keep code below the else.
    } else {
        cell.paymentNameLabel.text = (names.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)) as? String
        cell.costLabel.text = (values.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)) as? String
        cell.dateLabel.text = (dates.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)) as? String
        cell.notesLabel.text = (notes.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)) as? String

        if images.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as NSObject == 0 {
            cell.paymentArrowImage.hidden = false
            cell.creditArrowImage.hidden = true
        } else if images.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as NSObject == 1 {
            cell.creditArrowImage.hidden = false
            cell.paymentArrowImage.hidden = true
        }

        if notes.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as NSString == "" {
            cell.notesLabel.text = "No notes to display."
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Share the error message and the full class if possible.  This way we can see the class inheritances and the function constructions/protocol adherence.

Comment: There isn't anything displayed in the log, but I've added all of the code that is relevant to my question.

Comment: It sounds like you've accidentally created a breakpoint - stop execution and look for a little blue arrow in the gutter for that line (where the line numbers are). Drag the arrow out of the gutter to delete the breakpoint, and you shouldn't see the interruption again. **However,** you might want to [peruse Apple's debugging documentation](https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/debugging/) to learn about this essential part of building apps in Xcode!

Comment: Definitely no breakpoint unfortunately so that's not the problem. I do need to read up on breakpoints at some point however.

Comment: I think this would be easier to debug if you post the full project to github.